# Using Hibernate's session.get(type, someString) to retrieve object with correct capitalization on the <someString> primary key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I'm using Hibernate's Session to retrieve an object from a DB on a varchar primary key, and using `session.get(Foo.class, someString);` to obtain this object. My problem is `someString` can be "bob" or "BOB" and the object still gets retrieved (which is fine!), but the `Foo.someString` property is set to whichever capitalization was provided in the `session.get` argument, (let's say "BOB"), while the database property holds something different (let's say "Bob"). I actually need the retrieved object to hold whichever capitalization the database holds since I'm using that field for other purposes later on, but the input capitalization is provided by the user, so it could be anything. Instead `Foo.someString` ends up holding the user provided capitalization, which is not what I need, while all the rest of fields (that aren't ManyToMany collections) are retrieved for me correctly.

In other words, I need to use Hibernate to retrieve an entity `Foo` with the property `Foo.someString` set to "Bob", not to the user provided input, which could be "BOB", "boB", or any other capitalization variation.

Thanks.

Comment: A decent database should not return an entity whose ID is "BOB" when searching for "bob". You're probably using MySQL. I strongly suggest you disable that "feature", and you use a query to search for the entities matching the key, ignoring case. Something like `select foo from Foo foo where lower(foo.id) = lower(:searchedId)`. Using a string as ID, which has a functional meaning, and is thus probably mutable, is also not a good idea. Prefer purely technical, autogenerated IDs.

Comment: Thank you JB! Your posts have been very helpful throughout StackOverflow, the HQL query you provided is a quick fix for my issue. You're right, I am using MySQL, but I'll also take the rest of your advice to heart going forward.